# Handling ajax URLs from different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have my site at `http://example.com/foo/` (under a directory, the main domain is for something else).

Using .htaccess, I've set up my pages so the URLs look like `http://example.com/foo/about/`, `http://example.com/foo/polls/`, `http://example.com/foo/registration/`, etc. This works great and the site loads fine and can be traversed without any Javascript issues.

Now, I'd like to add some AJAX functionality to the navigation. If I'm on `http://example.com/foo/` and I click the navigation for "About", it changes the URL to `http://example.com/foo/#about` and dynamically loads the about page in one section of the site. I also have this working.

I have two problems which involve handling switching between AJAX and non-AJAX URLs.

- If I'm on `http://example.com/foo/about/` and I click on polls, it would look like `http://example.com/foo/about/#polls` which doesn't look very pretty. Ideally, I'd want every AJAX URL to be formatted with just the main directory and a hash, like `http://example.com/foo/#about`.
  Should I handle it by forcing an actual (non-AJAX) redirect to the index page with a hash symbol then load it from there?
- The other problem is the reverse. If I send `http://example.com/foo/#about` to someone who has Javascript disabled, or maybe if someone links to it and a bot crawls that link, is there any way to handle that to redirect to the correct non-AJAX page or is this just an unfortunate fact of life I'll have to deal with?

Answer (score 0):

If you need non-javascript support, I'd change all your urls directly to the pages.  Like `http://example.com/foo/#about` to `http://example.com/foo/about/`

Then, the javascript can intercept it, call `event.preventDefault()`, and 'redirect' it to #about, which will follow your ajax functionality.

If the client doesn't have javascript, it will go to `http://example.com/foo/about/` as normal.

As for being on `http://example.com/foo/about/`, a javascript client should never get here as they will always be redirected to hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you redirect to the main page and then use ajax to load the about page that would just not make much sense. what you should do is make everything work through ajax : there should never be a http://example.com/foo/about/ in the first place only http://example.com/foo/#about then you just update the hash and the content when you click on polls.

2) there is no way to avoid, sorry.